# jms serializer bundle serialize super class

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I use jms serializer bundle to serialize a super class but i want to serialize my super class like this:

```
/**
 * @Discriminator(field = "type", map = {"vehicle": "Vehicle", "car": "Car", "moped": "Moped"})
 */
class Vehicle { }
class Car extends Vehicle { }
class Moped extends Vehicle { }
```

but it doesn't work i can get fied 'type' in my json for children but not for my superclass Vehicle.
For instant i use an hack:

```
$data = $this->serializer->serialize($vehicle, 'json');
if(!strpos(",\"type\":", $data))
{
    $data = substr_replace($data ,",\"type\":\"vehicle\"}",-1);
}
```

to add my field and can deserialize my object after.

Have you any cleaner idea for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation:

> @Discriminator 
>   This annotation allows deserialization of relations
>   which are polymorphic, but where a common base class exists. **The
>   @Discriminator annotation has to be applied to the least super type.**

So I'm afraid there's nothing much you can do about it. However, I think I would do it like this (somewhat slightly cleaner):

```
if (($decoded = json_decode($data)) && !isset($decoded->type)) {
    $decoded->type = 'vehicle';
    $data = json_encode($decoded);
}
```

At least is more reliable I think. I hope it helps!

Comment: Ok it's much better than a simple string replace, I'm always afraid to add some parameter to an object and not in entity class with symfony2. But I don't know why jms discriminator doesn't work as ORM Discriminator.